# Creating a form in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to build a simple form in SharePoint. 
The version of the SharePoint is not important for me, because my form  is not going to be used by a real user and its not going to be uploaded to a real server. My windows is a 32-bit win 7.
Someone please help me. Here are my questions:
1- which version of the SharePoint should i install? 
2- Is it necessary to install windows server? 
3- Should i install Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007?
It's worth mentioning that my intention of doing this is to control the process of making the real forms which is going to be done by a company.

Answer (score 0):

You will need windows server for sure and also a 64bit environment. I would suggest to read the basics of MS SharePoint on the Microsoft websites, especially the installation and prerequisites sections...

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667264.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Verthosa for your answer.